# How to Output Terraform Module Variable Names

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm fairly new to Terraform and I have a question.

I have a bunch of terraform modules calling a main module to create a number of s3 buckets.

```
module "s3_1" {
  source = "../modules/s3-arc"

  ENVIRONMENT = var.ENV
  bucket_name = var.s3_dep["one"]

}

module "s3_2" {
  source = "../modules/s3-arc"

  ENVIRONMENT = var.ENV
  bucket_name = var.s3_dep["two"]
}

module "s3_3" {
  source = "../modules/s3-arc"

  ENVIRONMENT = var.ENV
  bucket_name = var.s3_dep["three"]
}
```

It so happens that the policies are are being created separately, and so there appears to be a race condition resulting in a `NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist` error because the policies are being created first.

I feel like in order to resolve this, I need to add an explicit dependency using `depends_on` but I can't seem to figure out how to output the bucket names being created by modules `s3-1`, `s3_2`, and `s3_3` so that I can add the `depends_on` under the policy section.

How do I output these bucket names please?

Comment: The modules should have an output whose values depends on the resource being created and depending resources need to reference that output.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your module you can declare an output value which returns some attribute of the S3 bucket, and optionally any other objects that contribute to the functionality of the bucket.

For example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      # I'm using resource types introduced in v4
      # below, so we'll need at least that version.
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "bucket_name" {
  type = string
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name

  # ...
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket

  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

output "bucket" {
  value = {
    name = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket
    arn  = aws_s3_bucket.example.arn
  }

  # The bucket won't be "ready to use" until
  # these other resources are created, so
  # these are "hidden dependencies" as described
  # in the documentation for depends_on
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_acl.example,
    aws_s3_bucket_versioning.example,
  ]
}
```

Using [`depends_on`](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs#depends_on-explicit-output-dependencies) with an output value means that any object which refers to this output value in the calling module indirectly depends on those other resources too, and so all three of the S3-related resources must be created completely before anything in the caller can make use of the S3 bucket.

When you separately declare the a policy for one of these buckets in the root module, you'd refer to the bucket name or ARN via the `bucket` output value, which therefore completes the necessary dependency edges to get a correct ordering:

```
module "s3_1" {
  source = "../modules/s3-arc"

  bucket_name = var.s3_dep["one"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "example" {
  # This reference to module.s3_1.bucket.name establishes
  # the needed dependency relationships.
  bucket = module.s3_1.bucket.name

  policy = jsonencode({
    # ...
  })
}
```